# can an android app in store (Google play or other) be free for existing users who have it preloaded and paid for others?

Tags: android, updates

If I would be lucky enough to have my app preloaded into certain Android devices, can I serve both preloaded customers & new ones from the same app instance in any given Android store? The app would be free for existing users and paid for new customers.

Related question would be about different Stores. Can I update my preloaded app using any Store available or do I have to stick to Google Play?

Answer (score 0):

It's not directly possible because the Google Play store doesn't let you change an app from free to one that costs money. If it has a cost, you can raise or lower it as you wish, but once it's free, it's free.

You could try to work around it with some form of in-app purchase, but this would affect existing users that choose to upgrade as well so it's a poor option.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would you hold the anser to my second question about updating preloads from different stores.

Comment: I am not 100% certain however I strongly believe the source of the install is not important, and that the Google Play store will still update the app as long as it has the same signing key and is versioned correctly. I had an app preinstalled by a phone OEM, and in this case, updates on Google Play were applied. Note that if you use the Amazon store, the signing key is not the same unless you uploaded your private key to them.