# Query Google Play for all users that have installed my App

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I would like to add a feature on my existing Android app, that allows old users to not pay (In-App Billing) for a new functionality that i am adding to the Application upgrade,
What i intend to do is:
Check if user has ever downloaded the app, if user has, allow user to use the new feature for free:
If this is a first time download, then user may have to pay(In-App Billing)  for the new feature.
I haven't, so far, seen anywhere where someone can query Google play for this.

I found this as related to the idea 
[can an android app in store (Google play or other) be free for existing users who have it preloaded and paid for others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571802/can-an-android-app-in-store-google-play-or-other-be-free-for-existing-users-wh) . But it doesn't really specify if i can query installer information from Google Play.
Basically is it possible to query Google Play and see if a user has ever installed my application... Yes, No, Maybe...

Comment: You cannot query Google Play. What you could try though is get the installation date from PackageManager.

Comment: In that case, what if the user uninstalled the App and decided to install it again, maybe not even on purpose, they lost their device maybe and decided to get the App again on the new Device. The date option may not work right?

Comment: I'm sure the date would get lost on deletion.